# Load a directory in a js with flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I would like to declare in a script, a directory.

```
$images_dir = '{{url_for('.../pictures')}}';
```

My flask application directory looks like:

```
Root
-wep.py
-templates
 -gallery.html
-static
-pictures
```

The picture are located inside the pictures folder, and the html page that contains the script is gallery.html which located in the templates folder.

The purpose of that script is to list all the images that are located in the pictures folder and present them as a gallery view when the gallery.html page is loaded.
The script works fine if I run it in a normal apache webserver though.

When I run the web.py, the debuger gives me the error:

```
BuildError: ('../pictures', {}, None)
```

So I think the problem is to declare the directory in flask.

UPDATE:
Im using this guy's script : http://davidwalsh.name/generate-photo-gallery

As you can see in the source code:

```
/** settings **/
$images_dir = 'preload-images/';
$thumbs_dir = 'preload-images-thumbs/';
```

Im trying to adjust those line to work with flask.

Comment: `url_for` wants an endpoint (e.g., a view), not a file system path.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what do you suggest to use, in order to load a system path?

Comment: JavaScript can't access system paths. You will need to provide it a list of images using something like [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Comment: The first question is updated with some more details.

Comment: That script is all PHP. `$images_dir = 'preload-images/';` becomes `images_dir = 'preload-images/'`, etc.

Comment: How is this suppose to help if I remove the $ symbol?  As far as I know $ is the way to declare variables.

Comment: The `$` is used for variables in PHP. You want to convert this script to Python. Therefore you need to remove the `$`.

Comment: I did what you advised me to but it still doesn't work. So by removing the $ from all the variable will convert the php code into a python one???.. Im quite lost now? Is it possible to run the php code as is using flask? Im quite new to flask. Sorry if my questions are so noob like.

Comment: Flask is written in Python. PHP and Python are two different languages. You cannot run PHP code inside your Flask application. A lot of work needs to be done to translate the script from PHP to something that will work with Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of `url_for`. `url_for` is for generating a link to one of your application's HTTP endpoints/view functions. You don't need any flask-specific method to get a list of files. You might find [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) or [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) helpful for this purpose. Then you can pass a list of the relevant paths to your template for rendering.